# How can I remotely install and uninstall a Click Once application?

Tags: windows-7, remote, clickonce

I have about 70 machines running Windows 7 and I need to perform two tasks on all of them:

1. Uninstall a previously installed Click Once windows application.
2. Install a new Click Once windows application.

Can I do this remotely using `psexec` or anything similar?

Comment: What sort of environment are you in? e.g. Do you use Active Directory?

Comment: These machines are on a private LAN in the agency and don't connect to the Windows domain controller or anything like they so they are basically "standalone"...